# sublime text 3 use python 3.3 as compiler

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext, python-2.x

Just purchased sublime 3. I'm wondering how I can compile in python 3 and not in python 2.

When I execute

*import sys 
print(sys.version)*

I receive 
"2.7.3 |EPD_free 7.3-2 (32-bit)| (default, Apr 12 2012, 14:30:37) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]"

I've been stuck for the last 2 or 3 hours. I know it has something to do with builds but it just doesn't seem to be clicking.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Alright I figured it out.

Change the default path for python.

Here is a great tutorial.

http://pythoncentral.org/how-to-install-python-2-7-on-windows-7-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/

Comment: I answered the question as community wiki so you can mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sublime Text Python builder uses the Python executable found in your PATH.

Instructions for Windows could be found here: http://pythoncentral.org/how-to-install-python-2-7-on-windows-7-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/