# Choosing Python version when running Python scripts from Sublime Text

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext

1)  I am getting error on the python script if i run it through sublimetext. How do i map my existing python to sublime text rather than using the one comes with sublimetext ?

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

---

```
 import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

i think the tool use its own python.

2) is there a short key like (the common F5) to run the script on sublimetext ? 
Please suggest.

Thank you

Comment: Almost duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287158/

Answer (score 0):

The Python builder in Sublime Text runs the active Python file with the Python executable found in your PATH. You can start it with Tools -> Build (Ctrl + B).